# How to modify/allow firewall rules of a GCP instance directly from the CLI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bash, ports, firewall

Is there anyway to allow the ports from CLI? 
I have an instance in GCP and I have installed a service which by default runs on `Port:8080`. I know there is an option to change the firewall rules to allow ports from the GCP dashboard but **I'm wondering if there is any way to allow the required ports from the CLI**
In my case I'm using `Git Bash` rather than the native `GCP Cloud Console` 
I have seen the documentation to allow ports from command line [GCP Firewall-rules-from CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/firewall-rules/create) but this is throwing a `ERROR` since I'm using the `Git Bash`. 
Here is the error log:

```
[mygcp@foo~]$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create FooService --allow=tcp:8080 --description="Allow incoming traffic on TCP port 8080" --direction=INGRESS
Creating firewall...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.firewall-rules.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

[mygcp@foo~]$ gcloud compute firewall-rules list
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.firewall-rules.list) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

Is there any option to allow required ports directly from the Git Bash CLI?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, you are using the wrong account.

Find out which one you are currently using in CLI:

```
gcloud config configurations list
gcloud auth list
```

If the selected configuration is wrong, fix it and then retry with `gcloud compute firewall-rules create`.